# How to paint the same opengl drawing in two different borland builder windows?

Tags: c++, opengl, c++builder

I have one borland builder window form in which is drawn an opengl item on a timer.
And I want to draw this opengl item simultaneously in anther borland builder window.

Should I use Pixel Buffer Objects, or Frame Buffer objects ?
with glReadPixels ? or glBindFrameBuffer ?
When need I call these functions ? before my drawing or after ?

Or is it simpler to call the RC or DC of my first form in the second form ?
If it is possible, how may i call it ?

Answer (score 1):

Create additional OpenGL contexts for the other windows, share the context objects using `wglShareLists` which also shares textures.

- If the same view (same resolution, rendering etc.) shall be visible:
  Use a texture as a framebuffer object's color buffer attachment, draw to this FBO. Then draw textured quads using this texture in all the windows.
- If different view: Render each window individually.

**Please not that there is no such thing like a *"OpenGL item"***. OpenGL deals with only a single primitive (=triangle, quad, point, line) at a time and there's no kind of persistency in a rendering.